# Can the magnetic flux of two separate magnets or electromagnets attract and follow each other when placed on top and bottom of a steel surface?

Tags: magnetic-fields, material-science

Similar to how magnets attract and follow each other when placed on the inside and outside of a wooden table, is it possible for two magnets or electromagnets to demonstrate similar characteristics when applied to a steel table? More specifically is it possible to construct two magnetic devices that attract and follow each other when placed on the inside and outside of a steel pipe?

**Details:**

Steel Pipe Dominations:

•   (Haigh magnetic permeability and saturation)

•   Outside Diameter: 5” Inches

•   **Wall Thickness Range:** .205” x .500” Inches

•   Length: 40’ Feet

[image]

Comment: I suppose you mean a non-magnetic steel, because your magnetic varieties will have a slightly different effect...

Answer (score 0):

You don't indicate the N/S direction or size of the magnets, but if they are small the magnetic field will take the lowest energy path through the steel and not extend to the other side. If they are large and powerful they may saturate the steel and most of the field will go to the magnet on the other side.